# Understanding と勝手が違っていけねえや

Tags: grammar, phrases

> スカーフの下のレイドデバイスを外そうとして、後部箱型荷台の整備クルーから知覚同調で通信が入る。
>
> 『──ノウゼン少尉』
>
> 「伍長、無線のスイッチが入ったままだ」
>
> 知覚同調と無線の双方から同じ舌打ちが一つ。
>
> 『**いけね**、そうでした。どうもこの、知覚同調ってのは無線**と勝手が違っていけねえ**や。何でじゃじゃ馬に加えてこれまでうちの隊で実験するんだか……と。弾薬の補充、また高速徹甲弾と成形炸薬弾が半々でいいっすよね』

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

What does the bold ていけねえ mean here? Does it mean the same as いけね? And what does 勝手 mean here? The 勝手 seems redundant because it's already clear that the 伍長 thinks the radio is different from 知覚同調.

Comment: 勝手が違う is a fixed expression. Have you looked up what it means?

Comment: @Jimmy Yang Yes, I have. But I still think 違う is enough here. And my focus is on the meaning of いけねえ.

Answer (score 3):

[いけない](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%84%E3%81%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/#je-2990) means *bad, wrong*. いけねえ is a colloquial variant and the first いけね is a light exclamation similar to English *My bad* or just *Oops* meaning the speaker made some mistake. いけね can be used only as an interjection.

知覚同調は無線と勝手が違っていけない literally means "知覚同調 is not good, being different from radio communication in terms of [勝手](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%8B%9D%E6%89%8B/#je-12857)". So simply put, without 勝手 it sounds like "知覚同調 is categorically bad in contrast to (good) radio communication".

勝手 is a word very hard to translate (as easily seen in the examples of the definition linked above), but means something like *direction* in a rather abstract sense. In the particular sentence it means something along the lines of "user experience", and the overall sentence says 知覚同調 is (at the moment) not handy or harder to use since it is different from radio communication that the speaker is used to.